# Acquia Drupal for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drupal, drupal-7, acquia

Where can I find Acquia Drupal for Ubuntu. I'm looking at Lynda's tutorial and when browsing through the link, I cant find the deb package for Drupal7.

Where can I find it?

Comment: I think every download possibilities for D7 are there : http://www.acquia.com/downloads

Comment: I cannot find any for Ubuntu. Please link me through the ubuntu version.

Comment: I guess you can dl the tar.gz and use the installer here : http://www.acquia.com/download-thank-you

Answer (score 1):

There is none AFAIK. You'll have to install the complete lamp stack yourself.
A short way to do that would be by running

```
sudo apt-get install lampserver^
```

Note the `^`. Then install your site in `/var/www/` location

Answer (score 1):

you could use the drubuntu  desktop as an alternative for the acquia desktop: http://drubuntu.github.io/drubuntu/